# How do I remove the global variables and still make this work?

Tags: java

I have this program but I need to remove the global variables. Been trying to move things around and rewrite parts but I can't really figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birds3
{   
    public static int maxIndex;                                                                           //These three lines are the ones I'm talking about
    public static String[] birds = new String[99999999];
    public static int[] numbers = new int[99999999];

    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        whatBird();
        inputCheck();
        birdInput();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void whatBird()
    {
        System.out.println("\nType 'END' to finish the program and display the most common bird. \n\nEnter anykey to continue.");
        return;
    }

    public static String inputCheck()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.toUpperCase().equals("END"))
        {
            end();
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static void birdInput()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= birds.length)
        {
            System.out.println("\nWhat bird did you see?");
            birds[i] = inputCheck();
            System.out.println("\nHow many did you see?");
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputCheck());
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static int getMaxIndex(int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            int newnumber = numbers[i];
            if ((newnumber > numbers.length))
            {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public static void end()
    {
        maxIndex = getMaxIndex(numbers);
        System.out.print("\nWell....I guess thanks for using this program?\n");
        System.out.print("\nThe most common bird that you saw was the " + birds[maxIndex] + " with " + numbers[maxIndex] + " being seen in total\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

If you could give me some tips on how to fix my issues then please do.

EDIT: Okay I've removed some of the global variables but something still isn't working. No matter what I enter or what value, if I enter end it'll always just print the first thing I entered and the first value. Whats the issue now?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class birds4
{   
    public static int maxIndex;

    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        String[] birds = new String[99999999];
        int[] numbers = new int[99999999];
        whatBird();
        inputCheck(birds, numbers);
        birdInput(birds, numbers);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void whatBird()
    {
        System.out.println("\nType 'END' to finish the program and display the most common bird. \n\nEnter anykey to continue.");
        return;
    }

    public static String inputCheck(String[] birds, int[] numbers)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.toUpperCase().equals("END"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            {
                int newnumber = numbers[i];
                if ((newnumber > numbers.length))
                {
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\nWell....I guess thanks for using this program?\n");
            System.out.print("\nThe most common bird that you saw was the " + birds[maxIndex] + " with " + numbers[maxIndex] + " being seen in total\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static void birdInput(String[] birds, int[] numbers)
{
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= birds.length)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("\nWhat bird did you see?");
            birds[i] = inputCheck(birds, numbers);
            System.out.println("\nHow many did you see?");
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to learn about using "real" Objects, instead of using all **static** methods and fields.

Of course, your main class needs to be **static** so that you can call it from the command line. But then you normally do things like:

```
public class Example {
  private final String exampleString;

  public Example(String exampleString) { this.exampleString = exampleString; }

  public String getExampleString { return exampleString; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example myExample = new Example("whatever");
    System.out.println("The not so global example is: " + myExample.getExampleString());
  }
}
```

That is the whole point of OOP: classes have non-static fields and methods; and you instantiate objects using new; and then each object has its **own** copy of those fields (whereas *static* fields are shared between all such objects; and thus "global"; and thus they should generally be avoided).

Answer (score 0):

By way of example if `String[] birds = new String[99999999];`  and `int[] numbers = new int[99999999];` are not global, and are needed by `birdInput();`, you pass their reference by :

```
 birdInput(birds,numbers);
```

And the signature of `birdInput()` should be changed to :

```
public static void birdInput(String[] birds, int[] numbers)
```

Note that in some cases you need to change the logic and / or returned values.